# Setup git in xcode 5

Tags: ios, git, xcode5

I've read and finish the tutorial of [Git Source Control with Xcode in iOS 7 by Rey Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/51351/how-to-use-git-source-control-with-xcode-in-ios-7).

I know how to use source control on XCode 5. However, I don't know how to setup the repository so that my other MAC unit can access and use it. I'm searching all over google and none I can't seem to find anything that helps me.

Do you have any good tutorials out there for basic repository setup in XCode 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you setted up your repository on XCode you need to push it to a server.

You can use [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) for that. Create an account on BitBucket then create a repository there.

For the sake of simplicity, after you create your repository you need to build your https link for your repository. Usually it is in the form :

`https://YOUR_USERNAME@bitbucket.org/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_REPOSITORY.git`

`YOUR_REPOSITORY` can be checked in the link at the top after you create your repository. Usually that link is in the form `https://bitbucket.org/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_REPOSITORY`.

Then go to your XCode and go to the Source Control and under "Working Copies" select your project then press configure.

[image]

After that add your bitbucket repository pressing "Remotes" and then pressing the "+" button and clicking "Add Remote".

[image]

The address in the following box is the one : `https://YOUR_USERNAME@bitbucket.org/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_REPOSITORY.git` .

Then do Source Control > Push.

On your other mac go again to the working copies > configure your_project. Add the BitBucket in the remote section and then do Source Control > Pull.

Comment: wow! thanks. I'll try this later. Im not on my desk right now.

Comment: how can you delete a local branch?

Comment: As far as I know you can't remove a local branch in XCode. You have to use the terminal. Go to your folder in the terminal and do  `git branch -d local_branch`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed instructions with screenshots! I just did this, took me 5 minutes. Now I can stop zipping and gmailing my source code to myself for safekeeping. ;-)

Comment: @skypecakes I am glad it helped you :). If you want to do more advanced stuff than XCode allows it you can use SourceTree (free) or Git Tower (paid). If you want to learn more about git I advise you this link - > http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/

Comment: Got some idea out of this how to configure XCode (I checked it in XCode 5) and followed a slightly different way out.